# Magento 2 new column in sales

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

Using it on magento version 2.3.1
I guess I am missing something if someone can help would be great!
I am trying to add country code column in the sales.

So far I've done the following:

> 1. I have added in sales_order_grid.xml

```
<column name="code">
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
 <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Code</item>
 </item>
 </argument>
 </column>
```

> 2. Created folder in app/code/Vendor/ExtendGrid/Module/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php 
    namespace Vendor\ExtendGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection; use Vendor\ExtendGrid\Helper\Data as Helper;

        class Collection extends OriginalCollection {  

        protected function renderFiltersBefore()  {  
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('directory_country_region');  
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, 'main_table.region_id = directory_country_region.region_id', ['code']);        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();  
    } 

} 

?>
```

3. Created folder app/code/Vendor/ExtendGrid/etc/di.xml

   > Vendor\ExtendGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection

Now I can see the new column code in sales but seems like I have missed something and cannot get the date from the DB table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to follow a tutorial like this

http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-a-custom-column-in-order-grid-in-magento-2/

I've not tested this.  But you should end up with something like this

app/code/Codextblog/Ordercolumn/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```xml
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="country_id" class="Codextblog\Ordercolumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Mycolumn">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

app/code/Codextblog/Ordercolumn/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Mycolumn.php

```php
namespace Codextblog\Ordercolumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use \Codextblog\Ordercolumn\Model\CustomFactory;

class Mycolumn extends Column
{

    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;
    protected $_customfactory;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        CustomFactory $customFactory,
        array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        $this->_customfactory = $customFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $countryId = $order->getShippingAdress()->getCountryId()
                $item[$this->getData('country_id')] = $countryId;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

app/code/Codextblog/Ordercolumn/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting">
        <plugin name="sales_grid_collection" type="\Codextblog\Ordercolumn\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order\Grid"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Codextblog/Ordercolumn/Model/Plugin/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
namespace Codextblog\Ordercolumn\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order;


class Grid
{

    public static $table = 'sales_order_grid';
    public static $leftJoinTable = 'sales_order_address';

    public function afterSearch($intercepter, $collection)
    {
        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {

            $leftJoinTableName = $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$leftJoinTable);

            $collection
                ->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(
                    ['soa'=>$leftJoinTableName],
                    "soa.parent_id = main_table.entity_id",
                    [
                        'country_id' => 'soa.country_id'
                    ]
                );

            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where);
            //echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();die;
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

That should get you near.  Potentially I missed part about filtering shipping address only

```php
 ->where('soa.address_type = ?', 'shipping')
```